# changing Majuscule and minuscule cases

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file containing lines with one word in upper case and one other word in lower case like this :

```
"BAMBARA"{ "bambara" }
```

As output I want to have :

```
case(BAMBARA) { template("bambara") }.
```

So far I have `sed/"$"/case($)/`
But it doesn't work at all. How can I do these specifying upper and lower case letters ?

Comment: Upper and lower case for non-Frenchies ;-)

Comment: Can you explain `sed/"$"/case($)/`?

Comment: I wanted to say if the value is between "" change it to case(value).

Comment: Looks like we got @jww-ed (user [jww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww) downvotes a question and all answers occasionally) so I'm upvoting everyone to compensate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/"\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)\("[^"]*"\)/case(\1) \2template(\3)/' file
case(BAMBARA) { template("bambara") }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed 's/"\([^"]*\)"{ \("[^"]*"\) }/case(\1) { template(\2) }./'
```

Answer (score 2):

An awk-command that uses `"` as field separator (a little dirty):

```
awk -F"\"" '{print "case("$2") { template(\""$4"\") }."}' inputFile
```

Answer (score 2):

a simple [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) would be

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\+\)/template(\1)/;s/"\([A-Z]\+\)"/case(\1) /'
```

notice that the order is important. If you invert it, you would match the word `case` as it is fully downcased.